# Spring Security deprecated methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, auth0

Currently I'm learning Java Spring Boot, and trying to implement auth0 in my backend app. I'm stuck with configuring SecurityFilterChain - in tutorial at spring academy they use deprecated methods to configure filter chain, authorizeRequests not used without parameters, but through lambda function. I found how to implement simple login-password authorization, but I want to use JWT token which I receive after login in my react app

Where I can read about latest usage of spring security, because both spring and auth0 resources use deprecated components?

Thank you and sorry if it is a dumb question, I tried google it

Comment: I'd be happy to help! I work for Auth0 and I've done a lot with Spring Security over the years. If you don't find an answer here, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered numerous errors while attempting to validate the token, with CORS-related issues being prominent among them.

By adding the following line to my app.properties, I discovered that the request method from my frontend was "OPTIONS" instead of the "GET" I had intended:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
```

To address this, I included a specific line in my matchers. While this resolved the issue, I'm uncertain about its security implications.

```
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/places/**").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

recently I also found this difficult, but somehow I managed to tackle this by learning the [lambda](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTa9YGfyhyW2CqdtW9RtY-I3) a little deeper.

and this is how I configured the '[securityFilterChain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxqlJblhzfI)()'

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {


    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authProvider;


    @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        (request)->
                                request
                .requestMatchers("api/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());
        http
                .sessionManagement(
                        (session)->
                                session
                                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider);
        http
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
   }
```

Comment: This answer has NOTHING to do with the question at all. How could an explicit configured SecurityFilterChain with specifically added AuthenticationFilter without any further explanation help a newbie? This is nothing but confusing.